# Como fazer Engenharia Reversa em arquivo xml compilado

Tags: xml, engenharia-reversa

Ola,queria saber se é possível abrir um arquivo AndroidManifest.xml compilado.
O mesmo arquivo esta em hexa.

Comment: Use `apktool`, https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/, ele é capaz de "decompilar" tudo, desde .xml até o código java em si, depois ainda pode modificar e compilar novamente (usando outra chave, obviamente). >:D

Comment: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Comment: não consegui usar apktool dava erro, mas achei outra opção.